# Getting ImageIcon absolute path from a Jlabel

Tags: java, jlabel, imageicon, absolute-path

**By using:**

`jLabel1.getIcon().toString();`

It returns only the reference to the object "`javax.swing.ImageIcon@2982ccce`";

Not the absolute path, so how could I return the absolute path of that Icon?

For example: `C:/File/imageicon.jpg`

Comment: toString() always returns object in string format. Try it without toString() like: jLabel1.getIcon()

Comment: Can't be done. Images and Icons do not have API for this, and can be used generally in contexts aside from the file system.

Comment: You can't, because an icon and a file are unrelated. You can create an icon by reading a file, but you can also create one by several other ways (from a jar resource, a socket, a byte array in memory, etc.)

Comment: @ArpitParasana Yea I will try that thank you!

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you!

Comment: @JBNizet Yes I understand, Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
    JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lk/edu/ijse/examsimulator/img/Hand With Pen_36px.png")));
    if (jLabel1.getIcon() != null) {

        Icon iconPath = jLabel1.getIcon();
        System.out.println(iconPath.toString());
        /* print      
         * file:/E:/Quick%20access/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ExamSimulator/ExmClientAdmin/build/classes/lk/edu/ijse/examsimulator/img/Hand%20With%20Pen_36px.png
         */

        String absolutePath = iconPath.toString().replaceFirst("file:/", "");
        absolutePath = absolutePath.replaceAll("%20", " ");
        System.out.println(absolutePath);
        /* print
         *
         * E:/Quick access/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ExamSimulator/ExmClientAdmin/build/classes/lk/edu/ijse/examsimulator/img/Hand With Pen_36px.png
         *
         * it's my image absolute path */
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some text on how your code answers the question. Perhaps, add an example with its output. Also, please consider re-formatting your code.

Comment: OP says `toString()` results in "javax.swing.ImageIcon@2982ccce"; you say `toString()` results in a file path, now how is right? Well, you both are, but you don't explain the difference in your code and why your `toString()` call acts differently.

Comment: Thank you.. I had some mistakes on that..Now I correct it..@Yannis

Comment: @Tom  I have no idea about that.. I am a trainee..
Please try it.

Comment: I guess you're also using an `ImageIcon`. If not, then you should add to your question. If you're also using an `ImageIcon`, then check how you initialize that and try to understand why your style of initialization allows it to print the path of the used file. Then you'll know the difference between your code and OPs one and that should be explained in the answer as well.

Comment: @Tom Oh, you are correct ..I had use ImageIcon 
Beacuse netbeans default also use ImageIcon..so I think it is better.. thank you.